# Hibernate Query and international characters

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, encoding, internationalization

I use hibernate in my Java SE application to query some data from database. But I need to use polish characters in where clause, for example:

```
where province='MAŁOPOLSKA'
```

**But the result set is empty.**

While using **SQL Server** I only need to add N letter before the 'Małopolska' string.
I tried to find a solution and the only thing I've found is putting those lines into config file

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
```

But It does not change anything, i.e I'm getting empty result set.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
I replaced plain 'MAŁOPOLSKA' string with the parameter, and it works fine. Example:

```
where province = :provName
q.setParameter("provName", 'MAŁOPOLSKA');
```